# 2000s Chinese animation where lightning strikes a boy's house, and he finds himself inside the world of the computer game he was playing

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, robots

I remembered watching a Chinese cartoon series about 10 years ago and it was probably made in the 2000s.

The story is about a boy that was playing on his computer late at night and lightning struck his house, then he found himself inside the world of the game he was playing.

He had a robot that became really powerful during the full Moon.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Note that you need two new lines to cause a paragraph break. Can you remember anything else about this? Anything that happens once he’s in the game, for example. If you do remember anything else please [edit] your question to include that information!

Comment: https://allthetropes.fandom.com/wiki/Trapped_in_TV_Land#Anime_and_Manga

Comment: The protagonist was in that video game world for the whole season not just one episode

Comment: Nevermind I found it

Comment: Don't forget to post your answer to help future readers! (You can answer your own question after 48 hours.)

Comment: @RegL - So, what was it?