# A 2000 ish Chinese show about a kid's house who gets struck by lighting due to playing games late at night and gets transported in the game

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, video-games

I remember watching about it about a long time ago.

The beginning was a kid playing some kind of game on his computer. His parents came to his room and told him to turn it off and go to sleep. He then fakes falling asleep and going back playing his game. Lightning strikes his house and he wakes in a desert wasteland setting.

He sees one of the character in the game defending some kind of fort and he somehow teaching him an ult. The people attacking were bootleg driodekas(I am pretty sure.) He somehow meets another character from the game defending something.

There was a helicopter base along with a big group of helicopter transformers. There was also a different kind of vehicle mech injured in there. The base falls somehow. I am pretty sure there was a mech group in a snowy biome. (I forgot the middle part)

The end of the season was them using pair ults to attempt to destroy the bosses. I am pretty sure there was a girl villain that gave the boss a strategy to switch locations so the pair ults don't do as much damage.

#### Characters

##### There were 6-8 good guys

- 1 red car use some kind of moonlight ult
- 1 blue car with (snow attack?)First pair
- 1 bulldozer who can smack ground and a giant boulder pops up
- (Forgot his partner)
- 1 (apache?) helicopter who uses his rotors as blades and some kind of twister ult
- Some kind of snow mech?(Not confident with this.)
- I forgot the last 2 guys.
  Also was pretty sure the boy could combine with one mecha to perform an ult in the beginning of the show.

##### There were (I am pretty sure) 3-5 bad guys.

- One was a boss driodeka(Pretty sure) and rolled into a ball to use a bouncing ult
- One was a flying boss
- One was a (gorrila boss?) He was slow but hits hard
- (Forgot one)
  And there was the girl villain

I am pretty sure it was this cartoon they were [talking about in this other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/247608/2000s-chinese-animation-where-lightning-strikes-a-boys-house-and-he-finds-hims).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Give us a range if you're not sure of the exact year. And could you explain why you think (or know) that this cartoon is Chinese? It could provide further clues as to what this is. Also, did you watch this on TV or online? If it was on TV, do you recall what channel in which country you saw it on?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GNYXEEmc-I - Code Lyoko?

Comment: Is this person describing the same cartoon? - https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/kxpod5/tomtcartoon2000s_3d_animated_chinese_mandarin/

Comment: What's an "ult"?

Comment: @LogicDictates It was around 2008-2015. I found the cartoon on a Chinese website online.

Comment: @Valorum It wasn't Code lyoko or the reddit post since there was no beach in season 1

Comment: @Buzz Special attack

Answer (score 4):

I think ***[The Adventures of Lolo of the Ever-Changing Beast](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%99%BE%E5%8F%98%E6%9C%BA%E5%85%BD%E4%B9%8B%E6%B4%9B%E6%B4%9B%E5%8E%86%E9%99%A9%E8%AE%B0)*** is the show you are looking for.

Translated from the Chinese Wikipedia page:

> "The Adventures of Luoluo", referred to as "The Adventures of Luoluo", is a three-dimensional animated series launched in Chinese mainland by Guangzhou Blue Arc Culture Communication Co., Ltd. and Xingjie Toys in 2009, directed by Wang Wei Served as a screenwriter and directed, with a total of 52 episodes, each about 22 minutes long.

> A computer game enthusiast, his favorite thing to play is a computer game called "Machine Warrior King". Because he was struck by a lightning bolt, he strayed into the game world and led the righteous and brave motorcycle tribe and the fierce and cunning beast race in a century showdown.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).